# PyQT5 doesn't call keyPressedEvent for Russian layout

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt5

So, I'm writing a simple [CHIP8](http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-write-an-emulator-chip-8-interpreter/) emulator. It obviosly needs some key input. The problem is, on starting the app system language changes automatically from English to Russian, and the app stops responding to keys with letters (numbers are working fine).

How can I change this behavior? Maybe, adding more keys to the dictionary below will help, but I could find any information about Russian keys in PyQT. Or is there some function, like `sys.change_system_language`?

Here is a code, which is responsible for key mapping

```
KEYBOARD = {
    Qt.Key_1: 1,
    Qt.Key_2: 2,
    Qt.Key_3: 3,
    Qt.Key_4: 4,
    Qt.Key_5: 5,
    Qt.Key_6: 6,
    Qt.Key_7: 7,
    Qt.Key_8: 8,
    Qt.Key_9: 9,
    Qt.Key_0: 0,
    Qt.Key_A: 10,
    Qt.Key_B: 11,
    Qt.Key_C: 12,
    Qt.Key_D: 13,
    Qt.Key_E: 14,
    Qt.Key_F: 15,
}
```

And this is main window:

```
class GameWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rom, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)    
        self.game = CHIP8()
        # more code here    

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() in KEYBOARD:
            self.game.key_pressed = KEYBOARD[e.key()]
```

Comment: why you did not use pyhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that whereas letters "Q" and "Й" are on the same button, theirs numerical values are different. So, to make everything work, I would need to add 16 new key-values pairs (getting all the Russian button's values by calling `print(e.key())` for every one of them). But I just switched keyboard default language to English :)